# Apple rejected app because of crash I cannot reproduce

Tags: ios

My app was rejected because of a crash on iPad, but I am  unable to reproduce it. What should I do?

> We found that your app crashed on iPad running iOS 7.0.4, which is
>   not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.
>           Your app crashed when we launch the app. 
>           This occurred when your app was used:
>
> - On Wi-Fi 
>         We have attached detailed crash logs to help troubleshoot this issue. For information on how to symbolicate and read a crash log,
>     please see Tech Note TN2151 Understanding and Analyzing iPhone OS
>     Application Crash Reports.
>         If you have difficulty reproducing this issue, please try testing the workflow as described in Testing Workflow with Xcode's
>     Archive feature.
>         For discrete code-level questions, you may wish to consult with Apple Developer Technical Support. Please be sure to prepare any
>     symbolicated crash logs, screenshots, or steps to reproduce the issues
>     for when the DTS engineer follows up.
>
>   2.10
>
>   Also, we found that your app crashed on iPad, which doesn't meet the requirements for running on iPad, as required by the App Store
>     Review Guidelines.
>
> This is the Crash Report.

```
Incident Identifier: BE08340B-BD3C-4834-A4B8-DEE44FDB8CF9
CrashReporter Key:   c9a77ef4dcc63290176c21a5175ca5807a28eca5
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             Lottery [670]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/470EA3B5-E92D-48AB-8DAD-66B4FB6F3950/Lottery.app/Lottery
Identifier:          CaiwangClient
Version:             1.0.0 (1.0.0)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-01-26 09:14:30.717 -0800
OS Version:          iOS 7.0.4 (11B554a)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x2d9bee83 0x381656c7 0x2d9beb89 0x2e37ae3f 0x2e2e0139 0xd5b3d 0xd52c9 0xca485 0x2e3a2e4b 0x2d989f1f 0x2d9893e7 0x2d987bd7 0x2d8f2471 0x2d8f2253 0x326002eb 0x301a7845 0xdf37f 0x3865eab7)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x387151fc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3877ca4f pthread_kill + 55
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x386c6029 abort + 73
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37b1498b abort_message + 71
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37b2d6e3 default_terminate_handler() + 251
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38165937 _objc_terminate() + 191
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37b2b1b1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x37b2ad13 __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3816580b objc_exception_rethrow + 39
9   CoreFoundation                  0x2d8f24e3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 639
10  CoreFoundation                  0x2d8f224f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
11  GraphicsServices                0x326002e7 GSEventRunModal + 135
12  UIKit                           0x301a7841 UIApplicationMain + 1133
13  Lottery                         0x000df37b 0x98000 + 291707
14  libdyld.dylib                   0x3865eab5 start + 1

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38702838 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x386510d1 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 229
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x3864b61f _dispatch_mgr_thread + 35

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38715c7c __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38779e07 _pthread_wqthread + 307
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38779cc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38702a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3870287d mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2d989555 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 153
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2d987c75 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2d8f246d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2d8f224f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
6   Lottery                         0x000d312f 0x98000 + 241967
7   Foundation                      0x2e3a2c33 __NSThread__main__ + 1059
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3877bc5b _pthread_body + 139
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3877bbcb _pthread_start + 99
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38779ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38702a84 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x3870287d mach_msg + 37
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2d989555 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 153
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2d987c75 __CFRunLoopRun + 789
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2d8f246d CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 521
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2d8f224f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
6   Foundation                      0x2e32d4bd +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 317
7   Foundation                      0x2e3a2c33 __NSThread__main__ + 1059
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3877bc5b _pthread_body + 139
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3877bbcb _pthread_start + 99
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38779ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38702ad4 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x3864fde1 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow + 173
2   libxpc.dylib                    0x3878a0d7 xpc_connection_send_message_with_reply_sync + 151
3   SystemConfiguration             0x3011d35b _reach_server_target_remove + 91
4   SystemConfiguration             0x3011d2cb __SCNetworkReachabilityServer_targetRemove + 39
5   SystemConfiguration             0x30104311 __SCNetworkReachabilityDeallocate + 93
6   CoreFoundation                  0x2d8eee2d CFRelease + 465
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x3864f7d5 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 221
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x3864f9c1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 53
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38779dfd _pthread_wqthread + 297
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38779cc0 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 6 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x38715440 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2d98d457 __CFSocketManager + 483
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3877bc5b _pthread_body + 139
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x3877bbcb _pthread_start + 99
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x38779ccc thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00002060
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3a2e618c      r6: 0x00000000      r7: 0x27d6b594
    r8: 0x14d6f380    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x00000000     r11: 0x001058cc
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d6b588      lr: 0x3877ca53      pc: 0x387151fc
  cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: Are you doing some threading? Seems like you constructed a deadlock... To be more precise, it seems like you embedded some Reachability lib. Maybe you are changing your UI in a background thread after being notified that something is reachable?

Comment: Drag the crash report into Xcode organiser to get it symbolicated and also the `Last Exception Backtrace` expanded. Once that is done, the exception should be clear, if not post the updated crash report in here.

Comment: Please symbolicate the crash using Kerni's instructions. The crash report is symbolicated when you see actual function names printed to the right of your "Lottery" module (in the fourth column), and not things like `0x98000 + 291707`.

Comment: I have send a HttpRequest on RootViewController's init method.is this a problem?but i still unable reproduce the crash after i try all the method that apple suggested.

Comment: 1. Please symbolicate, otherwise we nobody can help you! 2. Doing HTTP requests in Init methods are ALWAYS a bad idea. And if you are doing a synchronous request there the idea is far worse than just bad. 3. Please symbolicate the report first before doing anything else. I won't give any more answers otherwise and vote for closing the question.

Comment: Because i lost the latest archive,so i can't symbolicate,thanks for you response.

Comment: @duruochuan How did you lose the archive? It should only go away if you specifically delete it, which you should generally never do. Did you specifically move it to the trash and then empty the trash?

Comment: Yes,I made a stupid mistake